# Структура бд для ведения склада

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, архитектура

Возникла задача организовать свою систему учета ведения склада/складов.

После некоторого обдумывания у меня получилась следующая схема бд:

[image: версия 0.01]

где:

- **MeasureUnits** - *Справочник единиц измерения (кг/шт/прочее)*;
- **DocumentTypes** - *Справочник типы документов (Приходная/Расходная накладная)*;
- **Warehouses** - *Справочник складов* (Список складов);
- **MaterialAssets** - *Справочник подотчетных позиций*;
- **ROFs** - *Таблица для задания наличия необходимого минимального/максимального количества на складе*;
- **Documents** - *Таблица документов (Приход/Расход)*;
- **ItemsDocument** - *Таблица список позиций для документа*;

Помогите придумать как хранить остатки по складу, т.е. какие поля следует включить в таблицу: *Остатки*.

Был бы премного благодарен за советы касательно приведенной мной схемы: может что то стоит изменить.

---

**Update**

Наличие единиц измерения в приходной документации обусловлено тем что одна и та же позиция может прийти с другой единицей измерения, т.е. некоторые поставщики могут поставить в *штуках* а некоторые например в килограммах, соответственно бухгалтерия и приходует так же, и отсюда получается что в определенный момент на складе может быть одна позиция в разных единицах измерения

---

**Update2**
[image: версия 0.02]

в исходную схему внес следующие изменения:

- **ItemsDocument** переименовал в **DocumentItems**;
- в таблицу **ROFs** добавил поле **MeasureUnitId**, для того что бы было понятно в какой единице измерения отслеживать количество
- добавил таблицу **Units** - *Справочник подразделений*;
- добавил *макет* таблицы **Remains** в которой будут остатки;
- добавил таблицу **ConversionOfMeasureUnits**, в данную таблицу планирую записывать коэффициент который будет использоваться для приведения из одной единицы измерения в другую.

---

**Update3**

для чего я сделал связь между *DocumentItems* и *ConversionOfMeasureUnits*:

Предположим у нас на складе есть *Проволока*, в свое время она пришла в метрах и так и была оприходована, в один прекрасный момент эта проволока приходит в килограммах(поставщик сменился), в *DocumentItems* появляется запись следующего вида:

```
+----+------------+------------------+---------------+--------+
| Id | DocumentId | MaterialAssetsId | MeasureUnitId | Amount |
|----+------------+------------------+---------------+--------|
| 55 |     5      |         8        |        1      |    5   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

где:

- **5** - идентификатор документа;
- **8** - идентификатор товарно-материальной ценности;
- **1** - ед. измерения в чем был оприходован данный товар;
- **5,000** - оприходованное количество

что бы перевести полученные килограммы и показывать остаток в нужных нам метрах кладовщик, через интерфейс программы добавляет запись в таблицу *ConversionOfMeasureUnits* следующего вида:

```
+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| DocumentItemId | AtMeasureUnitId | TransformationRatio |
|----------------+-----------------+---------------------|
|        55      |        2        |         0,100       |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

где:

- **55** - идентификатор позиции в таблице *DocumentItems*;
- **2** - индетификатор ед. измерения в которую будем переводить;
- **0,100** - в данном случае это вес одного метра проволоки

имея подобную структуру я смогу *приводить* одну ед. измерения в другую, и отображать(возможно и хранить) остаток в нужных единицах, и в тоже время приход/расход будет вестись в тех же единицах что и в бухгалтерии

---

**Update4**

На основании предложений и советов изменил схему следующим образом.

[image: версия 0.03]

- Вынес ед. измерения в справочник материалов;
- Коэффициент преобразования связал со справочником материалов, добавил два поля типа `DateTime` дата начала действия и дата окончания действия(default value = "31.12.9999 23:59:59.99") коэффициента;

Comment: храните данные в накладных сразу в двух единицах учета - в базовой и в единицах накладной. Мало ли кто когда поменяет таблицы перевода...  И потом - никто не запрещает делать накладную разукомплектования. Хотя я бы не возился с материалами. У нас их списывают в работу в тех же единицах, в каких и пришли. Пришла бухта кабеля - никто не будет отмечать - сколько метров из нее ушло - списывается вся в работу на первую заявку. Не забывайте, что системой должны пользоваться люди не из Гарварда, которым нужны простые правила. ( с картинками :)

Comment: @DimaSUN про списание всего материала при первой заявке: цель то как раз видеть реальные остатки. на примере проволоки: приходуется в `кг.`, но фактически расход осуществляется в метрах, на основании коэффициента можно будет приводить `м.` в `кг.` средствами по, а по документам списание будет проводится в тех же единицах что и было оприходовано. *Не забывайте, что системой должны пользоваться люди не из Гарварда...* - а что Вам кажется сложным? опыта не так много, поэтому могу что то перемудрить

Comment: что я имел ввиду про людей - Им должны быть понятны их действия, т.е. бизнес-процессы, которые они выполняют. И систему учета начните именно с описания б-п. Если система будет значительно менять устоявшиеся б-п, то - независимо от качества системы - она умрет. Про саму систему - я б добавил МОЛ. Материалы не мгновенно со склада на склад прыгают... На первом складе отпускаете по заявке на МОЛ, на втором складе - приходуете с МОЛ на склад. На время перемещения за материал отвечает МОЛ. Ну и статусы документов нужно бы - Новый, отгружено, оприходовано, отмена - например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единицы измерения надо ставить на конкретный материал (товар), а не на запись документа. Т.е. что бы конкретный товар везде был в одних единицах. А то вычисление тех самых остатков на складе будет весьма нетривиально. На склад по документу завели 3 тонны сахара, по другим документам со склада отгрузили 30 кг, 45000 г и 2 мешка. Вопрос: сколько кубических дециметров сахара осталось при относительной влажности 80% и температуре 70 градусов фаренгейта ?

А остатки - это сумма всех записей по данному товару из ItemsDocument,  учетом отгрузок как отрицательных величин. Для удобства работы, и оптимизации по производительности можно либо фиксировать остаток на складе на конкретную дату или по точке ухода документов в архив. Или вести триггерами текущее значение. Структура во всех случаях простейшая:

```
MaterialAssetsId
WarehouseId
Ammount
Date -- возможно, если нужна, дата последней операции или фиксации остатка
```

Правда что то мне подсказывает, что следующим шагом развития системы будет отслеживать товары в пределах склада с указанием стеллажей или как там место указывается. Тогда придется делать много записей остатков с указанием размещения, например

**Upd:** ConversionOfMeasureUnits очень странно привязана к записям в документах. С одной стороны я конечно подозреваю, что какие то сложные пересчеты могут быть к документу. С другой стороны, представить перевод грамм в килограмм по разным формулам на разных документах очень сложно. Я бы в таком случае в DocumentItems добавил бы поле "кол-во в базовой единице измерения", в таблицу товаров добавил "базовая единица". Коэффициенты пересчета (хорошо если формулы не понадобятся, не дай бог жидкие материалы, для которых приходится учитывать плотность) вынес отдельно. И еще конечно надо подумать, что будет если в одной поставке мешки по 30 кг, а в другой по 35. Но тут вы похоже все равно хотели, что бы человек к конкретному документу эти коэффициенты откуда то брал. Может произвести "Стандартный расчет" и позволить исправить уже посчитанное кол-во в базовой единице.

С другой стороны, если отгрузка идет всегда в той же единице и пол-мешка отсыпать не пытаются, то тогда вопрос а нужна ли некая базовая единица. Базовая нужна если потом хотят выдавать какие нибудь статистические формы например, что бы в них товар был без разбивки на единицы. Но готовы ли ради них обеспечить перевод и ввод корректных "базовых количеств".

Comment: обновил вопрос. а как посоветуете быть с различиями в приходно/расходной документации, на текущий момент я не учел дополнительные поля в расходных документах (например затребовавшее подразделение). мне приходит в голову только разделение на две таблицы, может есть способ другой. и как хранить расход, как отрицательную сумму и тогда текущий остаток будет равен остаток + приход+расход

Comment: @Bald Смотря на сколько документы различаются. Если больше общего, то поля в эту таблицу добавить. Если сильно отличаются другую придется делать. Там правда возникает вопрос может ли товар вернутся из подразделения обратно на склад. А то во второй таблице точно плюсы минусы делать придется. По поводу хранения - или хранить отрицательную сумму или сделать справочник типов документов и там хранить коэффициент +1 -1. С единицами измерения конечно некрасиво. У вас остатки получаются то же в разрезе единиц измерения. И будет интересно смотреться передача в подразделение 2 шт и 1 кг

Comment: обновил вопрос, в приведенной мной схеме уже есть справочник типов документов(`DocumentTypes`), на основании которого можно заложить логику `+`/`-`. На сколько я знаю возврат на склад не осуществляется. про единицы измерения написал в обновлении. меня только смущают поля в `Documents` которые надо добавить для документов списания: это как минимум подразделение и комментарий, хотя с другой стороны две таблицы мне нравятся еще меньше. про следующий шаг Вы верно подметили :) можете дать рекомендации?! кстати отгрузка происходит в той же единице измерения что и приход

Comment: @Bald, ну пара полей которые в части документов NULL - это абсолютно нормально. А таблиц если их разносить даже 2 понадобятся. потому как DocumentItems под каждую таблицу документов придется свой городить или делать сложный выбор от какой таблицы порождена конкретная запись и там тогда появится идентичный код для работы с двумя таблицами итемов. В общем жесть. + обновил ответ. И надо на чем то останавливаться с остатками. Вам история по остаткам нужна или только текущие. Мне видится какой нибудь планово-экономический отдел, которому подавай помесячную форму по остаткам и движению за 5 лет

Comment: @Baid - я у себя сделал 2 типа документов - Приходные накладные и накладные перемещения. У меня нет партийного учета, а отслеживается движение каждой единицы. Поэтому на приходных накладных экземпляры рождаются, заполняется таблица Assets. При перемещении единицы из одного места в другое по заявкам в регистр учета перемещения заносится 2 записи - на старом месте - с минусом, на новом - с плюсом. Когда собираешь по местам ( заявкам, МОЛ  и т.п.) - видишь - где что. ( По приходной в регистр пишется одна запись ). Движение каждой позиции можно отследить по регистру.

Comment: обновил вопрос. на текущий момент интересуют только текущие, но это я уже проходил, могу сказать с 90% уверенностью что спустя какое то время понадобятся данные за прошедший период.

Comment: @Bald По последнему апдейту: по мне, так вводить не удобно кладовщику. он должен вычислить коэффициент и ввести его. И если у нас 200 поставок одной и той же проволоки в килограммах, а нам нужны метры. И кладовщику нужно к каждой из 200 поставок заново вводить один и тот же коэффиент

Comment: да возможно это не совсем удобно в случае если приход будет довольно частым, но описанная ситуация с разными единицами измерения все таки не такая частая, но она возможна и поэтому её надо предусмотреть. можете предложить иной способ решения? выносить ед. измерения из прихода, не представляется возможным что бы не потерять совместимость с бухгалтерией

Comment: @Bald Так в ответе написано. Максимум в справочник коэффициентов добавить вид товара. Если NULL - то коэффициент глобален для перевода данных единиц. Если задан - значит на данный товар

Comment: @Mike в очередной раз обновил вопрос.